# equating an entry to an aggregated version of itself

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to find if an entry's value is the max of the grouped value.  Its purpose is to sit in a larger `if` logic.

Which I'd expect would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.id as t_id, 
    sum(if(t.value = max(t.value), 1, 0)) AS is_max_value

FROM dataset.table AS t
GROUP BY t_id
```

The response is:

```
Error: Expression 't.value' is not present in the GROUP BY list
```

How should my code look to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to compile in a subquery the max value, then join again the value to the table.

Using the public data set available here is an example:

```
SELECT
  t.word,
  t.word_count,
  t.corpus_date
FROM
  [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] t
JOIN (
  SELECT
    corpus_date,
    MAX(word_count) word_count,
  FROM
    [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
  GROUP BY
    1 ) d
ON
  d.corpus_date=t.corpus_date
  AND t.word_count=d.word_count
LIMIT
  25
```

Results:

```
+-----+--------+--------------+---------------+---+
| Row | t_word | t_word_count | t_corpus_date |   |
+-----+--------+--------------+---------------+---+
|   1 | the    |          762 |          1597 |   |
|   2 | the    |          894 |          1598 |   |
|   3 | the    |          841 |          1590 |   |
|   4 | the    |          680 |          1606 |   |
|   5 | the    |          942 |          1607 |   |
|   6 | the    |          779 |          1609 |   |
|   7 | the    |          995 |          1600 |   |
|   8 | the    |          937 |          1599 |   |
|   9 | the    |          738 |          1612 |   |
|  10 | the    |          612 |          1595 |   |
|  11 | the    |          848 |          1592 |   |
|  12 | the    |          753 |          1594 |   |
|  13 | the    |          740 |          1596 |   |
|  14 | I      |          828 |          1603 |   |
|  15 | the    |          525 |          1608 |   |
|  16 | the    |          363 |             0 |   |
|  17 | I      |          629 |          1593 |   |
|  18 | I      |          447 |          1611 |   |
|  19 | the    |          715 |          1602 |   |
|  20 | the    |          717 |          1610 |   |
+-----+--------+--------------+---------------+---+
```

You can see that retains the `word` that have the maximum `word_count` in the partition defined by `corpus_date`

Answer (score 1):

Use window function to "spread" the max value over all relevant records.
this way you can avoid the Join.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    corpus,
    corpus_date,
    word,
    word_count,
    MAX(word_count) OVER (PARTITION BY corpus) AS Max_Word_Count
  FROM
    [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] )
WHERE
  word_count=Max_Word_Count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  id, 
  value, 
  integer(value = max_value) as is_max_value
from (
  select id, value, max(value) over(partition by id) as max_value
  from dataset.table
)
```

> Explanation:

Inner select - for each row/record calculates max of value among all rows with the same id
Outer select - for each row/record compares row's value with max value for respective group and then converts true or false into respectively 1 or 0 (as per expectation in question)